# Grunt jade error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jade

Whenever I run grunt jade I get an error:

```
Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function Use --force to continue.
```

Now here is my jade task:

```
    jade: {
        options: {
            pretty: true
        },
        all: {
            files: {
                expand:true,
                cwd: 'src/static/jade',
                ext: "html",
                src: ['src/static/jade/**/*.jade', '!src/static/jade/_includes'],
                dest: 'build/'
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically I am trying to take the jade files in `src/static/jade` (including subdirs, except `_include`) and put them in `build`, keeping the directory structure. I have tryed commenting the `expand` line, however it gives me:

```
 Warning: Unable to read "src/static/jade" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.
```

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your initial issues is that `files` should be an array of objects, not just an object: `files: [{...}]`.

But then you have other troubles with your file definition:

- if you specify `cwd`, your `src` should not repeat it
- your `ext` needs a starting `.`
- your ! pattern needs to specify files instead of a dir

So you need:

```
files: [{
       expand:true,
       cwd: 'src/static/jade/',
       ext: ".html",
       src: ['**/*.jade', '!_includes/**/*.jade'],
       dest: 'build/'
}]
```

Comment: The array thing was my issue. I just added the ext and cwd options to attempt to fix the error. Thnx!